# WCF NetTcpBinding in IIS

Tags: c#, wcf, iis

If the net.tcp Binding uses TCP as a transport protocol - how does this actually work in IIS, given that IIS in itself is a Web Server?

Just trying to understand how the technology works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since 7.0, IIS supports Windows Process Activation Service (WAS). WAS is a fundamental underlying component of IIS 7.0 that makes it possible to host WCF services beyond HTTP.

It allows the use of transport protocols other than HTTP, such as TCP, named pipes, and MSMQ (previously, IIS 6.0 only allowed the use of HTTP).

A complete explanation is available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734677.aspx).

Comment: I also found this very helpful explanation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163357.aspx

Answer (score 2):

IIS is not just a "web" server; it is designed to handle several protocols implemented on the TCP/IP stack.

net.tcp and HTTP are both implemented at the "Application Layer" of the [Internet Protocol Suite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_protocol_suite), so it's no surprise that a server that can handle one can be designed to handle the other. BTW, the transport mechanism for HTTP is TCP as well.